# Getting largest and second largest number in a sequence

Tags: java, sequence, max

Help me understand the last portion of this code that aims to print the largest and second largest number in a sequence. What I am not fully understanding is, what is the  need for the `else if` statement? with the code:

```
 if (input > largest) {
        secondLargest = largest;
        largest = input;
```

should that not do the job proper? it checks if input is greater than the largest number, sets the second Largest to the previous largest number. and update the new largest number with the one user inputed.

So what exactly is the purpose of this line of code then? and any reason the integers `largest` and `secondLargest` is set to `-1`and not just `0`, has it to do with the `sentinel` that breaks the program is set to `0`?

```
} else if (input > secondLargest) {
    secondLargest = input;
```

.

```
 int largest = -1;
  int secondLargest = -1;
  while (true) {
     int input = readInt(" ? ");
     if (input == SENTINEL) break;
     if (input > largest) {
        secondLargest = largest;
        largest = input;
     } else if (input > secondLargest) {
        secondLargest = input;
     }
```

Comment: Consider the input 8, 10, 9...so largest will be set to 8, second largest set to -1, and then for 10, largest is 10 and second largest is 8 but for 9, largest will remain 10 while second largest needs to be updated..also, I think the program wants to allow 0 so it sets the default -1.

Comment: If `input > secondLargest` but `!(input > largest)`, then without the `else if`, `secondLargest` will be incorrect.

Comment: The reason for initializing to -1 is that there apparently is an assumption that the sequence is all positive numbers. Zero means "end of sequence" and -1 means "not found" (or something like that).

Comment: So simple really! I don´t understand my brain can´t think of this itself. I hope it learns it after a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try your program with the sequence

```
    1 2 3 5 4
```

If you omit `else if (input > secondLargest) { secondLargest = input; }` then result will be largest=5 and secondLargest=3, that is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The `else if` code handles cases where `input` falls between the current values of `largest` and `secondLargest`.

Answer (score 1):

The `else if` part is if in case the `input` is not greater than `largest` but greater than `secondLargest`, when the `secondLargest` should change even though the `largest` will not.